# Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet when running it via Azure Devops

Tags: azure, powershell

When using the Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension command it works via the cloudshell but when I try to run it via Azure Devops pipeline I get an error "The term 'Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet" How can I get this working in Azure devops pipeline?

Comment: Which Task type you are using Azure PowerShell or just PowerShell? Which type of agent, self-hosted? If yes, is Az module is installed on your agent server in AllUsers scope?

Comment: in  Azure Devops pipeline I click ADD,  select Azure CLI task, in that task I then put in the above azure cli code. For that there are only the options : Powershell , Powershell Core, Bash and Shell. Also Task versions only 0, 1 and 2 and none of them worked. I chose Powershell

Comment: `Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension` is Az PowerShell module cmdlet, so you need [Azure PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops). If you want to use Azure CLI task, you need to use [az vm extension set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux#azure-cli). I recommend to not mix Az CLI et Az PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

Add a task prior to running the cmdlet:

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: Install PS module
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        Install-Module -Name Az.Compute -Force
```